# How to change the default email address for the non-root user in postfix?

Tags: debian, postfix, cron

I have a user called `admin` (not root) and have setup everything under that user's account.

I have also crontab that is meant to run a bash script at a certain time in the day.

For some reason the script fails and the system is trying to email me.  However there is no email setup for admin@mydomain.com.  How can I change the default email address for this user to be something else than the domain name `mydomain.com` that is stored in `/etc/mailname`?

```
Sep 27 09:45:01 SAPI CRON[18430]: (admin) CMD (bash /home/admin/backup.sh XYZ)
Sep 27 09:45:04 SAPI pgbouncer[747]: stats: 0 xacts/s, 0 queries/s, in 0 B/s, out 0 B/s, xact 0 us, query 0 us, wait 0 us
Sep 27 09:45:47 SAPI postfix/pickup[18366]: 9FAB67DECE: uid=1000 from=<admin>
Sep 27 09:45:47 SAPI postfix/cleanup[18451]: 9FAB67DECE: message-id=<20220927094547.9FAB67DECE@sapi>
Sep 27 09:45:47 SAPI postfix/qmgr[18367]: 9FAB67DECE: from=<admin@mydomain.com>, size=2820, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Sep 27 09:45:48 SAPI postfix/smtp[18453]: 9FAB67DECE: to=<admin@mydomain.com>, orig_to=<admin>, relay=email-smtp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com[52.58.161.38]:587, delay=0.57, delays=0.02/0.04/0.31/0.2, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 Ok)
```

Answer (score 1):

To redirect emails for user `admin` to another email address or user, create an alias in `/etc/aliases` :

```
admin: user # For a local user mapping

or

admin: user@remote.com # For a remote user mapping
```

then update tour aliases DB with `newaliases` command.